# Не могу настроить GitHub

Tags: git, github

Хочу папку со своего компа залить на github.
Делаю из GitBash команды:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/fenix63/site.git
```

и

```
git push -u origin master
```

и после второй, мне Gitbash пишет

> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/fenix63/site.git/':
>   Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to github.com:443

помогите пожалуйста, как избавиться от этой проблемы?

---

Я хочу именно по логину и паролю. Где то прочитал что проще всего это по HTTPS делать. В общем у меня для выхода в инет прокси используется. Я сделал вот эту команду:

```
git config --global http.proxy HOST:PORT
```

потом

```
git push -u origin master
```

Теперь GitBash мне вот что выдаёт:
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/fenix63/site.git/': Received HTTP code 407 from proxy after CONNECT

Comment: Вот [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20491027/unknown-ssl-protocol-error-in-connection) рассматривается почти аналогичная проблема, попробуйте приведенные способы.

Comment: @Dmitry если вы хотите просто оставить ссылку на другой вопрос, то для этого лучше использовать комментарии (пока что они недоступны, но скоро будут, так что совет на будущее).

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/using-ssh-over-the-https-port/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/128035/4827341

Comment: Сожалею, но по настройке прокси под Windows не смогу подсказать, не работал. Ответ удалю.

Answer (score 1):

> для выхода в инет прокси используется

тогда, как советуют в ответах к [этому вопросу](https://stackoverflow.com/q/128035/4827341), попробуйте настроить *git* на использование этого прокси-сервера:

```
 $ git config --global http.proxy http://ваш.прокси.сервер:порт
```